# Android Studio cannot find my R.layout

Tags: java

Android Studio cannot find R.layout.fragment_reddit_list for my Reddit project that I am working on. How can I solve this? Here is a line of code from my project for you to figure this one out and let me know if you do. Thanks!

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reddit_list, container, false);

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: Is the layout in the right folder, is the R class imported, do other references to R.* don't work either or is it just this one. Those are some standard questions that may help you find the error. I can't find it because you provide to few information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the layout xml, there should be some characters that are is not leading it to build properly, use online xml validator to verify layout.xml.